# Jquery Hide/Show not working on one div only

Tags: jquery, html

I have done some jquery to hide and show a div depending on what tab the user clicks. It works perfectly for all the other 3 tabs apart from the first one. I have no clue. It seems as though it is not hiding it when there is no active class - when I inspect there is no active class so an dumbfounded.

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
  jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      if($('ul.tab-links li.tab1').hasClass('active')){
      $(".tab-content").css({ 'background-color': '#cbd7d7' });
      $(".arrow").css({ 'border-color': '#cbd7d7' });
      $(".arrow").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(560px)' });
      $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab1").css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0)' });
      $(".tabs .tab-content #tab1.tab").show();
      }
      else {
        $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab1").css({ 'transform': 'translateX(1600px)' });
        $(".tabs .tab-content #tab1.tab").hide();
      }
      if($('ul.tab-links li.tab2').hasClass('active')){
        $(".tab-content").css({ 'background-color': '#ebebeb' });
        $(".arrow").css({ 'border-color': '#ebebeb' });
        $(".arrow").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(600px)' });
        $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab2-identity").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(0)' });
        $(".tabs .tab-content #tab2.tab").show();
        }
        else {
          $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab2-identity").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(-3000px)' });
          $(".tabs .tab-content #tab2.tab").hide();
        }
      if($('ul.tab-links li.tab3').hasClass('active')){
        $(".tab-content").css({ 'background-color': '#d5cebc' });
        $(".arrow").css({ 'border-color': '#d5cebc' });
        $(".arrow").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(650px)' });
        $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab3-touch1").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(0)' });
        $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab3-touch2").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(0)' });
        $(".tabs .tab-content #tab3.tab").show();
        }
        else {
          $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab3-touch1").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(-1300px)' });
          $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab3-touch2").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(1300px)' });
          $(".tabs .tab-content #tab3.tab").hide();
        }
      if($('ul.tab-links li.tab4').hasClass('active')){
        $(".tab-content").css({ 'background-color': '#eaeae2' });
        $(".arrow").css({ 'border-color': '#eaeae2' });
        $(".arrow").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(680px)' });
        $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab4").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(0)' });
        $(".tabs .tab-content #tab4.tab").show();
        }
        else {
          $(".tab-content .tab .image-tab4").css({ 'transform': 'translateY(1300px)' });
          $(".tabs .tab-content #tab4.tab").hide();
        }
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab1" class="tab">
<div class="image-tab1">
</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab" >
<div class="image-tab2-identity">
</div>
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab">
<div class="image-tab3-touch1">
</div>
<div class="image-tab3-touch2">
</div>
</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tab">
<div class="image-tab4">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
<ul class="tab-links">
<li class="tab1 active"><a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
<p id="more-info">paragraph.</p></li>
<li class="tab2"><a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
<p id="more-info">paragraph.</p></li>
<li class="tab3"><a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
<p id="more-info">paragraph.</p></li>
<li class="tab4"><a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
<p id="more-info">paragraph.</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Thanks for the comments - Upon reading the suggestion I managed to work it out but just adding

```
$(".tabs .tab-content div").removeClass("active");
```

under each if statement so that it first removes the active class from all and then adds it for the respective one.

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correct. This is your html.

```
<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
        <div class="image-tab1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab" >
        <div class="image-tab2-identity"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <div class="image-tab3-touch1"></div>
        <div class="image-tab3-touch2"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab">
        <div class="image-tab4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="tab1 active">
        <a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
        <p id="more-info">paragraph.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2">
        <a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
        <p id="more-info">paragraph.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="tab3">
        <a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
        <p id="more-info">paragraph.</p>
    </li>
    <li class="tab4">
        <a id="tablink" class="activetabcheck" href="#tab1">HEADING</a>
        <p id="more-info">paragraph.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On click of `tab-link`, you want to add class `active`.

CSS

```
.active
{
  //all your style stuff
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
 $("ul.tab-links li").on("click",function(e)
 {
  //get the index of li clicked.
  var index = $(this).eq();
  //remove actve class 
  $("div.tab-content").find("div.tab .active").each(function()$(this).removeClass("active")});

  //add class ative
  $("div.tab-content div").eq(index).addClass("active");
});

// Use this link to get more readable snippert - https://codepaste.net/cwiaad
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: typo `div.tab active` to `div.tab .active`

Comment: @Kgn-web thanks for this. Will give it a try. Just so I know what does .eq(); do? (so I learn). Will report back :D

Comment: @Kgn-web im getting an error in the console - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier it refers to the line: $("div.tab-content").find("div.tab .active").each(function()$(this).removeClass("active")});

Comment: @Kgn-web so I first tried the way you suggested to use .addClass and not hide/show.

If I change my code to be .addClass instead of .hide it works for the last 3 tabs but not the first one that is shown first. It is strange and in inspect element I can see all the others getting and loosing the active class but the 1st one doesnt. :(

Comment: @Kgn-web - all sorted - see update in my question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @PeterWilkinson, Sorry I was away & couldn't follow up on your comments.

Comment: @PeterWilkinson, your last comment say everything sorted, in case anything, please let me know.